# session.get() unable to resolve field,argument

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm totally new to Spring MVC but still trying to understand its methods and its way of referencing things. There's a video tutorial course I'm following.

I'm trying to implement a Model through a class.

**ProductDaoImpl.java**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(product);
        session.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public Product getProductById(String id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class.productId);
                        // unable to resolve the productId on get()
        return product;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteProduct(String id) {

    }
}
```

**ProductDao.java**

```
import java.util.List;

public interface ProductDao {
    void addProduct(Product product);
    Product getProductById(String id);
    List<Product> getAllProducts();
    void deleteProduct(String id);
}
```

**Product.java Model**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  //tells the system that when an instance is put to database, it will be numbered automatically starting from 1
    private String productName;
    private String productCategory;
    private String productDescription;
    private double productPrice;
    private String productDimension;
    private String productStatus;
    private int unitInStock;
    private String productManufacturer;
    private String productId;
}
```

However, it's unable to resolve the **productId** argument in

```
@Override
        public Product getProductById(String id) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class.productId);
            return product;
        }
```

Is `get()` method able to access the fields of `Product.class`?
Is it asking for a field in `Product.class.fieldHere?`

I don't understand why it can't resolve the `productId`

I hope you can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that in Spring, your DAO can be completely autogenerated by Spring Data; you just declare an interface, and it builds the DAO logic for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `Product.class.productId` doesn't make sense in Java. `Product.class` is a *class literal*, meaning that it's a constant value that represents the `Product` class, an instance of `java.lang.Class`. `Class` has no `productId` field.

Additionally, you should read [the Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable)) for the method--it takes two parameters, a `Class` object (to tell it what sort of thing you're getting) and an ID. Your call should therefore be `session.get(Product.class, id)`, and if you're using Hibernate 5, you don't need to cast to a `Product`.

All of this is rather moot, however--instead of hand-rolling a DAO targeting Hibernate, use JPA (which provides advantages such as a generic API, eliminating the need for casting) and Spring Data (which will autogenerate this entire DAO for you from nothing but an empty interface declaration). Additionally, you're dealing with topics that can get complicated, and you would do well to go through some exercises to learn core Java before tackling something like ORM.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I haven't used class literals in the past and I guess haven't checked that in a book I'm reading. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
session.get(Product.class.productId);
```

That's not valid Java code. get() expects two arguments: the entity class, and the ID of the entity to get. Arguments in Java are separated by a comma.

```
session.get(Product.class, productId);
```

But your variable isn't even named productId. It's named id. So the code should be

```
session.get(Product.class, id);
```

This is beginner Java stuff. I strongly suggest you practice with simpler Java exercises before using Spring and Hibernate, which are complex stuff.

Comment: Plus one for the advice on basic Java first.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks for the advice. I'll take note of that. I actually jumped to learning it because I was so interested but I guess I'll read more on those little things I must be familiar with. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

session.get accepts two parameters, one is the class of your entity and the other one is the identifier

```
    Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class,id);
```